# attributeeeror: opencv python on raspberry pi

Tags: c, opencv, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

When I try to run my code on python shell I'm getting following: 
Attributeerror:'picamera' object has no attribute 'capature'
please help

```
 import time
 import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
camera.start_preview()
# Camera warm-up time
time.sleep(2)
camera.capture('foo.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the recipe from the picamera website, line 5 thru 9 are indented as they are part of the python 'with' statement.

Suggest you check the code is indented and correct. Your error message has a misspelling.